# Can we calculate AUC for deep learning based regression task

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras, scikit-learn, regression

There is  a paper [ref.attaced[]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7849133), where they used a deep  learning based regression and evaluated using mse and AUC. The targets are continuous values such as 1,2,3 up to 16 and has been normalized before training.
Is it possible to calculate  the AUC for regression task.?

Comment: Please give the reference. (A reference, please, not a link. Links can break.)

Answer (score 1):

AUC is for **binary classification** tasks only, it's not possible to calculate it on a regression model. However it's plenty of other metrics one can use to check a regressor performance, such as **MAE** and **MSE**.

Comment: There are ways of being clever and making ROC curves for multiclass problems: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html.